# Wrong Knotes indicator in indicator-applet-complete on BB 18.04

Tags: icons, 18.04, indicator

After installing Knotes, I'm getting the wrong indicator on the taskbar (the 'delete note' icon). Everything works, but the Knotes indicator icon is wrong. Other apps (Veracrypt, Xpad, both appearing to the left of the indicated wrong icon) show up fine.

[image: Screenshot displaying incorrect icon as indicated by arrow]

It's a small niggle, but it bugs me. :) What could cause this and what can I do about it?

Comment: The icon you're seeing indicates that, for whatever reason, your system hasn't found the appropriate icon. Does the icon theme you're using have `knotes.png`? Can you temporarily switch to the `hicolor` icon theme? That has  `knotes.png` as indicated by the output of `find /usr/share/icons/hicolor -iname knotes.png`. If that works, I'm guessing any other icon theme that has `knotes.png` should also do the job.

Comment: Instead of `knotes.png`, some themes may have `knotes.svg`.

Comment: I think you're onto something here. The configured theme is Ambiance, and switching to hicolor doesn't seem to be an option. Looking into it from that angle. Tnx!

Comment: Ambiance is the gtk theme. I'm talking about the icon theme.

Comment: That fixed it. Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be caused by the knotes icon(s) not being present under /usr/share/icons/Humanity (the elected icon theme was Humanity). Solution: replace the missing icons.

Comment: Unfortunately, replacing the missing icons doesn't seem to help. Either I'm supplementing the wrong icons or I'm missing something else. There doesn't seem to be a way to determine which icon image the indicator applet tries (and fails) to load.